# Is there a certain pattern with the prime factorization of numbers adjacent to each other.

Tags: prime-factorization

So, recently, I was playing around with random numbers and their prime factorizations in my free time. Basically, what I would do, was take a number, say x.

I would take the prime factorization of x, then add 1 to x, and try comparing the prime factorizations of, both to see if there is a pattern that is present.

Let's assume x to be 24 here:

$24 = 2^3 * 3$
$25 = 5^2$

I can't really seem to find a pattern over here, Aside from the fact that 5 is the sum of 2 and 3. I was wondering if there is some sort of pattern to this specific example, or even better, a sort of pattern to any general example. If not, is it possible to find one? And if the prime factorizations are truly random, is there some way to prove it?

Yours Sincerely,
Aster17

Comment: There probably won't be much of a pattern, other than the obvious - the two numbers won't have any prime factors in common.

Comment: What you state is of course, obvious, but, there has to be something else that is there right? Perhaps using the sum of the prime factors?

Comment: Nothing that works in general. In number theory, the relation between addition and multiplication is complex. The most general idea (unproven so far) is the $abc$-conjecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abc_conjecture

Comment: So the thought of something like this is still under work. That is interesting.

Comment: No useful relation is known between the prime factors of $n$ and $n+1$ (except that they share no prime factor). Otherwise factoring would be much easier. The prime factorizations is , as far as we know , chaotic , and also the sequence of prime gaps is it. They are both not "truly" random (not even random in the usual sense) since they are completely determined. A pattern within the prime numbers is a very old dream and will almost surely keep a dream forever.

Comment: So, basically, they're very chaotic, but not exactly random. I can see that. Thanks a lot Peter, that is also a very interesting way to put it, might I say. You should considering becoming a poet hehe.

Comment: I do wonder if there could be something interdimensional about this? Maybe if we look at multiplication and addition to be on different dimensions, such as maybe addition being 2d, and multiplication being 3d, what if maybe that is why it is so difficult to determine? I know it sounds like utter nonsense, but maybe, just maybe?

Comment: Given any two distinct primes $p$ and $q$, there is always a multiple of $p$ followed by a multiple of $q$ by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. So, any two distinct primes whatsoever could appear in the factorizations of consecutive integers.

Comment: @Aster17 "Still under work" is a strong statement. The kind of pattern you are trying to find is definitely not there. The $abc$-conjecture is a very different animal.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I am very much an amateur at math, haha, I am simply a school student, so I definitely do not the best way to describe something in math. My apologies and I can see what you mean, as I go through the abc-conjecture, it does seem to be radically different, sorry for the pun there.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thank you very much for that piece of information.